# Stuck on text-select/text-highlight on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, mouse, gedit

I'm running a guest Ubuntu 14.04 on VMWare and whenever I'm editing text in gedit or another editor sooner or later the cursor gets stuck in text-highlight mode which means that left clicks highlights everything I click on.

This doesn't happen on my windows host so it isn't a mouse issue. I tried every keyboard shortcut but it doesn't resolve the problem. Only restarting the OS helps.

I didn't find too much about this online and nobody had a solution so far.